# Mysql ,JSP ,Google Maps

Tags: mysql, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have explored some of the interesting Google Maps Tutorials.I am interested to show Info Window and Markers on custom Google Map  on my application.Where i want to get data for info Window and markers from MySQL and instead of using php i want to use JSP.
     I have searched a lot on Google.I did not find any particular solution for this.Can anyone help me or give me hint on how i should go for it? Or Do I have to learn php now? Because i am good in JSP.
    Any help would be more appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am glad to answer my own question which was posted on stack overflow approximately 7-8 months back.

Question :- I wanted to display google map and some google map features in jsp (Not in PHP). Features such as InfoWindow etc.

Problem :- All GoogleMap feature logic was present in JavaScript. So I wanted to get my business data(which might contain some lat and longs) from mysql db inside javascript and show that data inside infowindow or use that data to put some markers on google maps etc. All this I wanted to do inside JSP's javascript.

Solution :- There are 2 solutions I found out

1) Use servlet which will return you data which you need in json format and call that servlet url inside javascript using ajax calls.

2) Use Spring MVC. Spring MVC return json object with @ResponseBody annotation specified inside your controller's method and you just have to call that url in same way as we will call servlet inside javascript using ajax call.

sample Ajax function :-

```
$.ajax({
          type:       "post",
          url:        "/ServletReturnJson/JsonServlet",//URL to your servlet
          dataType: 'json'
          success:function(msg) {
          var m=msg;
          var json = m ,
          obj = JSON.parse(json);
          for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
              //Iterate your data
          }     

      });
```

Note :- Above is just sample. You can try with your own classes and use above sample as guideline.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to read and understand [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3).  Implement the concept using JSP rather than PHP.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I am working on same example. I have followed exact steps which are there in tutorial. However when i run that application map does not on shownphpsqlajax_map_v3.html . Page is blank

Comment: Then something is wrong.  As you have not provided a link to your map or any information about your implementation, it is hard to guide you on how to fix it.

Comment: I read that tutorial carefully. I come to know my mistake. I have done some sample tutorials with some different data. I will soon come up with some doubts. Thanks ...